# Exchange GAL only showing Company name in iOS search results

Tags: active-directory, exchange, apple-ios

My organization uses iPads connected to our Exchange server. When we search the GAL for a person in the company, the results are shown as the Company only (data coming from the 'Company' field in Active Directory) instead of the contact's name.

Here are the steps I'm taking:

- I go to Contacts app, select 'Groups', then select 'Global Address List'
- I type in a name of a person I'd like to email. For example I type John to search for all the Johns in the company.
- I get a seach result that lists anyone with John in their name. The problem is the search results list the company name instead of the user's/contact's name. (If the 'Company' field is blank in Outlook/Exchange, I CAN see the user's name).

So my search results for John look like this:

COMPANY
COMPANY
John Smith
Sarah Johnson
COMPANY
COMPANY
COMPANY
John Deer
COMPANY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. The accounts I was having problems with had blank Firstname and Lastname fields for the Exchange users.